# When setting the route in <a> tag, the tag got hidden

Tags: laravel

1. I tried `Route::view(), Route::redirect(), redirect(), url()` all of these function in `<a>` tag. But after using them `<a>` tag got hidden.
2. What's function I have to use to get filter data using  month.

```php
    @for($i = 0,$carbon->month = 1; $i < 12; $i++)
        <a class="btn-disable btn btn-sm primary-btn" target="_blank" href="{{ Route::view('/virtualcabinet/vc_auto_datatable', 'viewName'); }}">
        {{$carbon->format('M')}}
        </a>
        <?php  $carbon->month = ++$carbon->month; ?>
    @endfor
```

Comment: Put your view page code here. I think there must be a typo in your code, an open tag or quotation in your code.

Comment: Try this `<a href="{{route('route_name', [$route_variable])}}">Text Link</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have redundant ';' after your route definition:

```
 @for($i = 0,$carbon->month = 1; $i < 12; $i++)
    <a class="btn-disable btn btn-sm primary-btn" target="_blank" href="{{ Route::view('/virtualcabinet/vc_auto_datatable', 'viewName') }}">
    {{$carbon->format('M')}}
    </a>
    <?php  $carbon->month = ++$carbon->month; ?>
@endfor
```